# How do i get my script to nicely reject invalid characters

Tags: python

at the moment if you put a character instead of a number in the input it gives an ugly error. I would like the script to output something like "Invalid character! Please enter a digit." whats something i can do to fix this?

```
import random
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userLetterInput = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?: "))
userSymbolInput = int(input("How many symbols would you like in your password?: "))

letterResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(userLetterInput)])

symbolResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.number_symbols) for i in range(userSymbolInput)])

print("".join(letterResult + symbolResult))
```

Comment: Research how to handle exceptions in python

Comment: use exception handling http://easypythondocs.com/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try/except statement in a loop to catch the exception and display a message for the user. The try/except statement catches the exception thrown when the user enters alphabetic characters, whereas the loop repeats the query for a number until the user gives a valid input.

```
import random
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

while True: # Repeat the question until valid input is given
    try: # Catch ValueError which gets thrown when letters are entered
        userLetterInput = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?: "))
        break # Exit the loop if no exception is thrown
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid character! Please enter a digit.")

while True:
    try:    
        userSymbolInput = int(input("How many symbols would you like in your password?: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid character! Please enter a digit.")

letterResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(userLetterInput)])

symbolResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.number_symbols) for i in range(userSymbolInput)])

print("".join(letterResult + symbolResult))
```

Instead of using a `while True` loop, you could of course also declare a boolean (e.g. `invalid_input`) which is `True` at first and gets set to `False` after the user entered a valid number.

Answer (score -1):

you can check input type with "isinstance":

```
isinstance(1, int)
isinstance('be', str)
```

Comment: No. "It's better to ask for forgiveness than check for permission"